# from where to start the select option menu

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I've got a select option menu for example with 10 options. When I open the page I want it to be on the 5 element. Example

```
<select name="categories" id="news_cat">   
        <option value="0">Volvo</option>  
        <option value="1">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="2">BMW</option> 
        <option value="3">Volga</option>
        <option value="4">Lada</option>  
        <option value="5">Porsche</option>     
      </select>
```

When I open the page I see the first option Volvo,but I what to be for example BMW. If you are going to say to change their place, this is not the idea because I gave you a simple example. In my case the idea is other

I also forget to say that "selected" can't help because I read all of the values from database

```
<select name="categories" id="news_cat" selected="1">   
        <option value="0"></option>  
        {foreach from=$categories item=i}                              
            <option value="{$i.id}"> {$i.name|stripslashes} </option>            
        {/foreach}    
      </select>
```

Comment: That was a big detail to miss out. In that case you want a js option if offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript solution:    `selectObj.options[2].selected=true;`

http://jsfiddle.net/8dWzB/16/

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply selected or selected="selected" to your chosen element.

so with your example:

```
<select name="categories" id="news_cat">   
        <option value="0">Volvo</option>  
        <option value="1">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="2">BMW</option> 
        <option value="3">Volga</option>
        <option value="4" selected>Lada</option>  
        <option value="5">Porsche</option>     
 </select>
```

Comment: please see the question I forgot to add something.

Answer (score 1):

Add `selected` or `selected='selected'` to option

```
<select name="categories" id="news_cat">   
        <option value="0">Volvo</option>  
        <option value="1">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="2">BMW</option> 
        <option value="3" selected>Volga</option>
        <option value="4">Lada</option>  
        <option value="5">Porsche</option>     
      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

No sure what server side technology you are using , but regardles of that, you can do what you like on the client side using JQuery.  Try the following:-

1) Get the data from your database into a list of objects having the `id` and `name` of the each car. Something like the following:-

```
`var categorylist = [{"id":"1","name":"volvo"},{"id":"2","name":"Mercerdes"},{"id":"3","name":"BMW"},{"id":"4","name":"Kia"},{"id":"5","name":"Toyota"},{"id":"6","name":"Honda"},{"id":"7","name":"Seat"},{"id":"8","name":"Nissan"}];'
```

You can then get this list to the client-side using `ajax`  `post` or `get`

2) Then you can iterate through the object like this

`$.each(categorylist, function (index, car) {`

```
    if(car.id !='5') {
       $("#news_cat").append('<option value="' + car.id + '">' + car.name + '</option>'); 
    }else
    {
        $("#news_cat").append('<option selected=selected value="' + car.id + '">' + car.name + '</option>');
    }
});
```

Have a [look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf7fh/1/)